# Android Studio can't recognize Galaxy Tab 4

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, driver

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 WiFi only and I have a problem connecting the tablet with Android Studio.

If I connect it without USB-Debugging it's shown like a mass storage.

If I enable USB-Debugging than I get the unpluged sound of windows every 2 sec.
This Driver is installed http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SM-T530NYKAXAR

I have installed this driver also http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

But no one of this is working. What do I can do to make this work?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Install MoboRobo and let it install your drivers automatically, Hope it will works then.